# How do I parse a PDF without reading the images?

Tags: pdfbox, text-parsing

I am parsing a PDF file but I do not want to extract the information stored in images and tables. I am using PDFBOX. How can I remove the images?

Comment: this is too brief. maybe a wonderful question but at least put some effort to fix it. "hi guys look I tried this and it didn't work. BTW this is what i wanna do. Is this code Ok? No?!? can you help?" *expert*: "ah you need to do XYZ and 123. on the right track tho!!"

Comment: Why are you parsing the PDF? Or is your question how to render a PDF without rendering the images?

Comment: I am taking the text from the pdf and putting it into a string. I don't want the content of the images to be in my string. How to do I exclude the images?

Comment: If you do text extraction, then you don't have to care about the images. An image can't be "in a string". Currently, did you start anything at all? If yes, what went wrong?

Comment: *I am taking the text from the pdf and putting it into a string. I don't want the content of the images to be in my string. How to do I exclude the images?* - If you do text extraction with PDFBox, you should use its `PDFTextStripper` class. This class does *not* include image data.

Answer (score 0):

```
pdftotext -raw <pdf_name.pdf> <output.txt>
```

This will strip out all the formatting, and return the strings which are in the PDF, no images.

Comment: The OP stressed he was using pdfbox.

Comment: I am providing other options, why does it matter to you? If your comment was the correct answer, why didn't you submit it?